# Adding content script by simple-prefs

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've got a content script that should be added on page if I select this preference in addon settings. I can add bool setting, but I absolutely can't understand how to operate with it on main.js file. The setting is

```
  "preferences": [{
        "description": "",
        "name": "tagHide",
        "type": "bool",
        "value": false,
        "title": "Hide something"}]
```

And in the main file I added this

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var prefs = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs;
function onPrefChange(prefName) {
    if (prefs.tagHide) {
        console.log(prefs.tagHide);
        pageMod.PageMod({
            include: "*.corbina.net",
            contentScriptFile: data.url("cutter.js")
        });
    };
}
```

This code logs "true" of "false" in the console, but pagemod seems not working. Any errors I've got here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with this code as-is:

- you don't bind onPrefChange anywhere in this code, eg `require("sdk/simple-prefs").on("", onPrefChange);`, see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs#on%28prefName.2C_listener%29)
- you don't apply the page-mod to existing tabs, see the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29) specifically the `attachTo` option.
- even if your page-mod attached, there is no way I can see that you unload the content script's effects?

Comment: Thanks alot, added onPrefChange and it works like a charm. Still sarching about how to remove contentscript though